# Need Help with update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I was hoping someone could look at this and give advice on how I can make this action better.  It works how I like it, but it seems unnecessary to create two model instances.

I felt that I had to do this because, even though update_attributes won't update the database if the validation fails, I still wanted to have the @user instance available to show the original @user.photo in the view.  I'm using paperclip.

Thanks very much in advance.

```
def edit_avatar

    @user = User.find(@username_id)
    if params['post_data'].present?
        @user.update_attributes(params[:post_data])
        @errors = @user.errors
        if @user.errors.count == 0
            @start_jcrop = true
        else
            @user = User.find(@username_id)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reloading the model, you can use [Dirty Changes](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html) feature.
Or you can use

```
@user.reload
```

instead of creating a new instance.

```
@user = User.find(@username_id)
  ...
  else
      @user.reload
  end
end
```

You can also simplify the view as follows

```
@user = User.find(@username_id)
if params['post_data'].present?
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:post_data])
    @start_jcrop = true
  else
    @errors = @user.errors
    @user.reload
  end
end
```

and if you skip the reload

```
@user = User.find(@username_id)
if params['post_data'].present?
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:post_data])
    @start_jcrop = true
  else
    # render
    # the previous image is available at
    # @user.attribute_name_was
  end
end
```